# SPFx environment variable for CI / CD for SharePoint on-premise

Tags: spfx, 2019, azure-devops, bitbucket

I have 3 environments in SharePoint 2019

1. Development Environment - corp.xxxUAT.com (AD) - Single Box Farm
2. Staging Environment - corp.xxxUAT.com (AD) - 6 Server Farm
3. Production Environment - corp.xxx.com (AD) - 6 Server Farm

When I work on development, I always keep my files in debug mode and upload SPFx package where files will fetch from gulp server.

In staging and Production I always upload build version of SPFx package.

Now I have few question

1. I am using 3rd Party api in SPFx. API are hosted locally in each environment, so how can I put different URL in coding for each environment, so I don't have to change when I build upload to Staging and Production
2. How can I use Jenkins and BitBucket in above context

Comment: You should ask these two questions as two separate questions.

Comment: Also, `window.location.hostname` or `window.location.origin` won't work for you?

Comment: IF by "API are hosted locally in each environment" means they're in e.g., /api/xyz in each environment, you could just omit the FQDN from your API call so call would be just "/api/xyz" and not "https://corp.xxxUAT.com/api/xyz".

Comment: @JussiPalo Hoted locally means in same network but not the sharepoint web application For example webapplication URL https://sharepoint.corp.xxxUAT.com and web api can be https://webapi.corp.xxxUAT.com/api/xyz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved two issue

1. **Building packages for different environments or tenants**
   [image]

1. Create your SPFx project and develop  as you do normally
2. Install  spfx-build-url-rewrite plugin

   `npm install spfx-build-url-rewrite --save`
3. Then in gulp.js to use this module.  Just before the initialize method you need to add two lines so it looks like this

   ```
   const rewrite = require('spfx-build-url-rewrite');
   rewrite.config(build);

   build.initialize(gulp);
   ```
4. Now when you build the solution you append the argument --target-cdn to replace the URLs in your solution, as follows:

   ```
   gulp build --target-cdn https://fabrikam.sharepoint.com
   gulp bundle --target-cdn https://fabrikam.sharepoint.com
   gulp package-solution
   ```

[Reference](https://www.wictorwilen.se/blog/how-to-generate-sharepoint-framework-bundles-for-multiple-tenants/)

2. **Building environment variables depends on environments / tenants**

1. Add “node” to the known types in tsconfig.json

   ```
   {
       ...,
       types: ["node", "webpack-env"],
       ...
   }
   ```
2. In the root of your project, create 2 files:

- .env – this can contain shared, non-sensitive settings. For example: log severity level, interval settings,
- .env.local – this will contain your settings. The settings which you use to run the application. For example: API base URL, AAD app ids …

3. Install dotenv and dotenv-expand in your project:

   `npm install --save-dev dotenv dotenv-expand`
4. Then, create a file process-env.js in root of your project, which looks like this:

   ```
       "use strict";

       const fs = require("fs");
       const path = require("path");

       const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || "dev";
       const dotEnvPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), ".env");

       const dotenvFiles = [
         `${dotEnvPath}.${NODE_ENV}.local`,
         `${dotEnvPath}.${NODE_ENV}`,
         NODE_ENV !== "test" && `${dotEnvPath}.local`,
         dotEnvPath
       ].filter(Boolean);

       dotenvFiles.forEach(dotenvFile => {
         if (fs.existsSync(dotenvFile)) {
           require("dotenv-expand")(
             require("dotenv").config({
               path: dotenvFile
             })
           );
         }
       });

       const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
       process.env.NODE_PATH = (process.env.NODE_PATH || "")
         .split(path.delimiter)
         .filter(folder => folder && !path.isAbsolute(folder))
         .map(folder => path.resolve(appDirectory, folder))
         .join(path.delimiter);

       const SPFX_ = /^SPFX_/i;

       function getClientEnvironment() {
         const raw = Object.keys(process.env)
           .filter(key => SPFX_.test(key))
           .reduce((env, key) => {
             env[key] = process.env[key];
             return env;
           }, {});

         const stringified = {
           "process.env": Object.keys(raw).reduce((env, key) => {
             env[key] = JSON.stringify(raw[key]);
             return env;
           }, {})
         };

         return { raw, stringified };
       }

       module.exports = getClientEnvironment;
   ```
5. Next, append gulpfile.js and add this right before the build.initialize() call:

   ```
           const webpack = require("webpack");
           const getClientEnvironment = require("./process-env");

           build.configureWebpack.mergeConfig({
             additionalConfiguration: cfg => {
               let pluginDefine = null;
               for (var i = 0; i < cfg.plugins.length; i++) {
                 var plugin = cfg.plugins[i];
                 if (plugin instanceof webpack.DefinePlugin) {
                   pluginDefine = plugin;
                 }
               }

               const currentEnv = getClientEnvironment().stringified;

               if (pluginDefine) {
                 pluginDefine.definitions = { ...pluginDefine.definitions, ...currentEnv };
               } else {
                 cfg.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin(currentEnv));
               }

               return cfg;
             }
              });
   ```
6. Than run below command and per your requirement

`set NODE_ENV=dev&&gulp serve --nobrowser --target-cdn http://revamp.corp.sharepoint.com`

[Reference](https://digitalworkplace365.wordpress.com/2020/03/05/using-env-files-in-sharepoint-framework-development/)

**The trick for it to work on Windows is you need to remove the whitespace before and after the "&&"**

Hope this will somebody

Comment: I needed to remove the white space before the `&&`. For some reason the `set` command includes the white spaces up to the `&&` in the value applied to the environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

As Dylan suggested, `window.location.*` in JavaScript is usually sufficient.

If you'd rather do it at build time, you can use *webpack-merge* and *DefinePlugin*.

First install `npm install webpack-merge --save-dev`

Then in your gulpfile.js, define different API URLs:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const build = require('@microsoft/sp-build-web');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const webpack = require('webpack');
build.addSuppression(/Warning - \[sass\] The local CSS class .* is not camelCase and will not be type-safe/gi);

build.configureWebpack.setConfig({
    additionalConfiguration: function (config) {
        let defineOptions;
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'DEV) {
            console.log('***********    Applying development settings to webpack *********************');
            defineOptions = {
                '_ApiHostUrl_': JSON.stringify('https://localhost:8810/')
            }
        } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'TEST) {
            // specify production keys here
            defineOptions = {
                '_ApiHostUrl_': JSON.stringify('https://your-test-api.com/')
            }
        } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'PROD) {
            // specify production keys here
            defineOptions = {
                '_ApiHostUrl_': JSON.stringify('https://your-prod-api.com/')
            }
        }

        return merge(config, {
            plugins: [
                new webpack.DefinePlugin(defineOptions)
            ]
        });
    }
});

build.initialize(gulp);
```

Finally install cross-env, and modify your gulp build commands to include environment in the NODE_ENV variable

```
"build-dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=DEV gulp serve"
"build-test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=TEST gulp serve"
"build-prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=PROD gulp serve"
```

In your code, use it like `_ApiHostUrl_`.

[Source](https://spblog.net/post/2018/06/24/Read-and-manipulate-SPFx-configuration-values-in-your-code-like-a-boss)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have achived same with dotenv & dotenv-expand but is their any way that we can pass **NODE_ENV** from CLI. This help to configure jenkies